# How to make button press change button background color and pressing again change it back on Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Im creating my first app on Xcode and cant solve a problem to make a button change color on press and change back when pressed again.

I have found a code on previous topics here and I have created a button and created a function

```
@IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        if button.backgroundColor == UIColor.black {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else if button.backgroundColor == UIColor.red {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }
}
```

I run the code on simulator and i get an error on line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { = Thread 1: signal SIGABRT .
```

How can I make this code work correctly?

I tried M. Mansueli and Abishek solutions and both give me the same result with error: On the bottom left corner is the error i get after running on simulator. (On the picture there is M.Mansueli code)

[On the bottom left corner is the error i get after running on simulator. (On the picture there is M.Mansueli code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxpCC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a @IBOutlet reference of your button in your class like in the image:

[image]
[image]

Now you can change the color on press using like this:

add this code in your viewdDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .black), for: .normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .red), for: .highlighted)
}
```

add a UIImage extension:

```
extension UIImage {
public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {

    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
}
}
```

Comment: Hm I get an error Argument labels '(color:)' do not match any available overloads .  Any advice on  that?

Comment: @zummer sorry, I forgot to add the extension to make this UIImage

Comment: And I run to an error on the same place like at start with error: Thread 1: breakpoint 1.4  . I placed extension after UIKit and before class. Guess thats right place?

Comment: @zummer I recommend to create a new File with name UIImage+Extension and add the extension UIIMage code inside

Comment: Seems im still doing something wrong. I updated my post with the picture from my Xcode on the first post.

Comment: @zummer Can you share your code in a git repository?

Comment: @M-Mansueli My first time using a git repository, so there may be something missing or maybe you meant i need to share something more. But thats what I shared now https://github.com/tzummer/firstapp

Comment: You forgot to close your extension UIImage }, and remember to change your button to a clear color to work the effect you want.  button.backgroundColor = .clear

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes. It works, but not the way i meant. It changes color when i click on it and does not stay that way. I need it to change color when i press to red and stay red and change back black when i press again. Did I still do something wrong or I did not say clear enough what i wanted to achieve? (Updated git repository with changes)

Comment: I think is this effect you want : override func viewDidLoad() {
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .black), for: .normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: .red), for: .selected)
        button.tintColor = .clear
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        button.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onButtonTapped)))
    }
    
    @objc func onButtonTapped() {
        button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
    }

Comment: Super. Now it does what I wanted to achieve. Big Big thanks for having the patience to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

First make @IBOutlet of that button and in your function do it like.

```
@IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if buttonOutlet.backgroundColor == UIColor.black {
        buttonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else if buttonOutlet.backgroundColor == UIColor.red {
        buttonOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

}
```

Comment: So I created  @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!  under class. Is that correct way?    Now I get an error in the same place Thread 1: breakpoint 1.4